# How to access starred questions

Tags: support

When I find helpful question that I might need to read the answer to it later, I check the star, I tried to find a way to access the questions that I starred but couldn't find the link.
Is there a link to questions starred by user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in the [favorites tab](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/20193/georges?tab=favorites) on your profile under *Activity*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! couldn't find it among all the other links, must be age.